# What is the easiest way to spawn multiple tasks under Linux and monitor their progress?

Tags: python, distributed-computing

I wrote a script (in Python) which grabs sentinel data, analyses it, reports to mongo db and etc. To make it work faster, I wrote spawner script, which split the task into N chunks and spawns N copies of script in separate `tmux` sessions.

I can attach to session and see how each individual script works, but can't control overlall progress.

What are common and simplest tools to do my work, with minimal script modification, so that I can distribute script between machines and processes and control overall progress?

Comment: Are these sub-process's ? if yes you can poll on the status using `Popen`

Comment: I run them with Popen, but I run `tmux`, which runs python script in turn

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a tool that accomplishes what you want. There might be one of course. I was considering building my own tool for similar purposes. But I'm very happy to learn if other users can suggest some existing infrastructure for that kind of problem. This is quite an interesting question you present here!